# Powershell "Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount" error

Tags: powershell, authentication, powerbi, powershell-cmdlet

I'm experiencing an issue concerning this command (Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount), I everytime get the same error :

> Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount : **Failed to populate environments in settings**
>
> Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
>
> - Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount
> - CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Power...IServiceAccount:ConnectPowerBIServiceAccount)
>   [Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount], Exception
>
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Failed to populate environments in settings,Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Profile.ConnectPowerBIServiceAccount

I've tried various things already like :

```
$password = "mypassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$user = "surname.name@company.com"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, $password)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential
```

or

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Environment Public
```

or

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -TenantId "company.com" -ServicePrincipal -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

I get the same result as well with *Login-PowerBI* or *Login-PowerBIServiceAccount*.

And I can't use *-CertificateThumbPrint*, I don't have access to the Power BI liscence key of my company.

All the PowerBI modules for PowerShell are installed (and I tried as well reinstalling them), my current version of Powershell is 5.1.19041.1645 and my .NET Framework version is 4.8

If you have any clue they are welcome.

Comment: Try to execute `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` before the call to `Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount`. It could be due to a TLS version mismatch when calling `https://api.powerbi.com/powerbi/globalservice/v201606/environments/discover?client=powerbi-msolap` endpoint.

Comment: I tried unfortunately same outcome

Comment: After couple of others tries without success, I was wondering, does this issue could be caused by a proxy setting or the fact that I'm not network admin ? (windows account is admin tho)